# Prove log24 base 4 is irrational

Tags: logic, proof-writing, solution-verification

I'm a bit stuck on the end of this proof.

[image: Picture of question]

Here is what I have so far:

We prove by contradiction.

Assume log4 24 is rational.

Therefore, log4 24 = m/n. m∈Z, n∈Z+.

So, 4^m/n = 24.

This is where I am not too sure where to go.

Comment: Hint;  that's the same as $4^m=24^n$.

Comment: @lulu Thank you, and then would that show it is irrational because of unique factorization?

Comment: That would work. Or, more simply, remark that $n$ can't be $0$ and that $3\nmid 4^m$ for any $m$.

Comment: @lulu Thank you very much!!